# No module cv2 found even though it is installed

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

This program is a blemish remover application using Python using OpenCV. I am getting an error saying that it can't import OpenCV.  This is the code:

```
def selectedBlemish(x,y,r):
      global i
      crop_img= source[y:(y+2*r),x:(x+2*r)]
      #i=i+1
      #cv2.imwrite("blemish"+str(i)+".jpg",crop_img)
      return identifyBestPatch(x,y,r)
def identifyBestpatch(x,y,r):
      #nearby patches in all 8 directions
      patches={ }

      key1tUp= appendDictionary(x+2*r,y)
      patches['Key1']=(x+2*r,y,key1tUp[0],key1tup[1])

      key2tUp= appendDictionary(x+2*r,y+r)
      patches['Key2']=(x+2*r,y+r,key2tUp[0],key2tup[1])

      key3tUp= appendDictionary(x-2*r,y)
      patches['Key3']=(x-2*r,y,key3tUp[0],key3tup[1])

      key4tUp= appendDictionary(x-2*r,y-r)
      patches['Key3']=(x-2*r,y-r,key4tUp[0],key4tup[1])

      key5tUp= appendDictionary(x,y+2*r)
      patches['Key5']=(x,y+2*r,key5tUp[0],key5tup[1])

      key6tUp= appendDictionary(x+r,y+2*r)
      patches['Key6']=(x+r,y+2*r,key6tUp[0],key6tup[1])

      key7tUp= appendDictionary(x,y-2*r)
      patches['Key7']=(x,y-2*r,key7tUp[0],key7tup[1])

      key8tUp= appendDictionary(x-r,y-2*r)
      patches['Key8']=(x-r,y-2*r,key8tUp[0],key8tup[1])

      #printing(patches)

      findlowx={}
      findlowy={}

      for key, (x,y,gx,gy) in patches.items():
            findlowx[key]=gx

      for key, (x,y,gx,gy) in patches.items():
            findlowy[key]=gy

      y_key_min=min(findlowy.keys(),key=(lambda k: findlowy[k]))
      x_key_min=min(findlowx.keys(),key=(lambda k: findlowx[k]))

      if x_key_min == y_key_min:
            return patches[x_key_min][0], patches[x_key_min][1]

      else:
            #print("return x & y conflict,can take help from fft")

            return patches[x_key_min][0], patches[x_key_min][1]

def appendDictionary(x,y):
      crop_img=source[y:(y+2*r),x:(x+2*r)]
      gradient_x,gradient_y = sobelfilter(crop_img)
      return gradient_x, gradient_y

def sobelfilter(crop_img):
      #along x-direction
      sobelx64f = cv2.Sobel(crop_img,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=3)
      abs_xsobel64f=np.absolute(sobelx64f)
      sobel_x8u=np.uint8(abs_xsobel64f)
      gradient_x=np.mean(sobel_x8u)

      #along y direction
      sobelx64f = cv2.Sobel(crop_img,cv2.CV_64F,0,1,ksize=3)
      abs_ysobel64f=np.absolute(sobely64f)
      sobel_y8u=np.uint8(abs_ysobel64f)
      gradient_y=np.mean(sobel_y8u)

      return gradient_x,gradient_y

def blemishRemoval(action, x, y, flags, userdata):
      #referencing the global variables
      globalr, source
      #Action when LMB Pressed
      if action==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            #MARKING THE CENTER
            blemishLocation=(x,y)
            #printing(blemishLocation)
            newX,newY = selectedBlemish(x,y,r)
            newPatch = source[newY:(newY+2*r), newX:(newX+2*r)]
            cv2.imwrite("newpatch.jpg",newPatch)
            #create mask for new patch
            mask=255*np.ones(newPatch.shape,newPatch.dtype)
            source=cv2.seamlessClone(newPatch, source, mask, blemishLocation, cv2.NORMAL_CLONE)
            cv2.imshow("Blemish Removal App", source)
            #Action to be taken when LMB released
      elif action==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
                  cv2.imshow("blemish Removal App", source)



if __name__== '__main__':
      import cv2
      import numpy as np

      #lists to store the points
      r = 15
      i=0
      source=cv2.imread("Raya.jpg",1)
      #,making a duplicate to work upon
      duplicate = source.copy()
      cv2.namedWindow("Blemish Remover")
      #cv2.resizeWindow("Blemish Remover app", 900,900)
      print("using a patch ofradius 15:")
      cv2.setMouseCallback("Blemish Remover app", blemishRemoval)
      k=0
      #Loop till character is pressed
      while k!=27 :
          cv2.imshow("Blemish Removal", source)
          k=cv2.waitKey(10)& 0xFF
          #other way of cloning
          if k==99:
              source=duplicate.copy()
              cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Just try running `import cv2`, does that raise the same exception?

Comment: This is probably happening because you are running a different distribution of Python than the one with the actual OpenCV install.  However, we can't begin to help you here without further information.  Show us what you did to produce the error, including every error message you receive from the beginning up to this point.  Your question is unfortunately out of topic for Stack Overflow as we are not able to reproduce your error.  Please take the [tour] and please visit [ask] to improve your question.